# CollapsingToolbarLayout with FloatingActionButton bugs

Tags: android, floating-action-button, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

Hello I'm creating a simple scrolling activity in my Android app. The scrolling acivity has a CollapsingToolbarLayout with parallax effect and a floating action button anchored to the AppbarLayout.

When i scroll the text down the fab disappears and when I scroll it back up the floating action button appears again.

The bugs are

1) when the floatingActionBar reappears it is positioned at the bottom end of the page and after a second it moves up to its correct position (appbarlayout). 
2) there is a strange margin that I can't figure out between the toolbar and the content of the page.

Since this is very ugly to see I wanted to know:

1.How can I solve this?
2.How can I keep the fab visible and anchored to the collapsed toolbar?

Here is the demo of the bug: http://i.giphy.com/LPMqLSl46Yvu0.gif

Here is my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="toxotes.mystikon.EventActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_event"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                android:src="@drawable/test"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>
            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_event"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_event" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_event"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_media_play"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar_event"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Here is the content_event layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="toxotes.mystikon.EventActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_event">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/text_margin"
        android:text="@string/large_text" />

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Here is the java:

```
public class EventActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_event);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_event);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab_event);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Which android design support version you are using ?

Comment: 'com.android.support:design:24.2.0'

Comment: Try with 'com.android.support:design:24.1.1'

Comment: Burhanuddin, it didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just today I had exactly the same problem. You have to update the support library to version 24.2.1. in your build gradle. This fixed it for me.

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
}
```

But then I got problems with vector drawables:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: This app has been built with an incorrect configuration. Please configure your build for VectorDrawableCompat.
```

Here’s the solution in case you run into the same problems: http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2016/02/android-support-library-232.html